# Category Carousel/Slideshow Pattern Exists? Good idea?

Tags: design-patterns, user-interface

We are a small publishing house with about 1.5 content updates per week. Most of our stuff is highly technical in nature with a broad audience of practitioners and academics. So, one might only find an item to be of interest once in a while if something is published in your area of expertise. Most of our traffic comes in from a search or from our opt-in content pushes.

Our current homepage loads all content in a a content column with an article teaser pattern in chronological order (as done a million times over in the last decade). The user has to scroll, and scroll to spot a title of interest or complete a search.

We would like to implement a carousel of sorts as this is a common pattern users understand, but we are still hung on the fact that you have to scroll and scroll to look for a title/image/teaser to pique your interest. We would like the user to be able to choose the category from a list of our most popular and diverse subjects and have the carousel load only those items. See this website for an example of a slideshow with category options: http://www.bensky.co.uk/my-work.

In my opinion, most surfers understand a well implemented carousel/slideshow. However, it seems to me that this category slideshow is probably too complex. Ultimately, the goal is help the user find all of our recent material that is relevant to their area of expertise with minimal complete page reloads and perma-scrolling.

Do you think the category carousel is too complex. Is there an alternative?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a question here?

A 'carousel' is just a simple Div with pictures flowing (animated) in and/or out of it depending on which button you click. Extremely simple, shouldn't take more then an hour for you to write, including organizing those articles into categories.

Note: 'animation' is not complicated. Its only a loop that says 'every 100ms, move div a to the left 100px'; Easy.

Comment: I removed the javascript tag to keep with design patterns and user-interface. Technical implementation is not a problem.